# Hartl Tutorial chapter 10 Factory Girl error - factory not registered: micropost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am getting this error in relation to:  "Authentication authorization in the  Microposts controller submitting to the destroy action"

spec/requests.authentication_pages_spec.rb:119

The only solutions I have seen to this involve restarting the rails server and/or spork (which I am not using) have restarted the server though.

git://github.com/princeofburma/sample_app.git

spec/requests.authentication_pages_spec.rb

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
      it { should have_error_message }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_error_message }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Users', href: users_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
        before do
          visit edit_user_path(user)
          fill_in "Email", with: user.email
          fill_in "Password", with: user.password
          click_button "Sign in"
        end

        describe "after signing in" do
          it "should render the desired protected page" do
            page.should have_selector('title', text: 'Edit user')
          end

          describe "when signing in again" do
            before do
              click_link "Sign out"
              click_link "Sign in"
              fill_in "Email", with: user.email
              fill_in "Password", with: user.password
              click_button "Sign in"
            end

            it "should render the default (profile) page" do
              page.should have_selector('title', text: user.name)
            end
          end
        end
      end

      describe "in the Users controller" do

        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
          it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-notice') }
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { put user_path(user) }
          specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end

        describe "visiting the user index" do
          before { visit users_path }
          it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        end

        describe "visiting the following page" do
          before { visit following_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        end

        describe "visiting the followers page" do
          before { visit followers_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        end
      end
    end

    describe "in the Microposts controller" do

      describe "submitting to the create action" do
        before { post microposts_path }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path)}
      end

      describe "submitting to the destroy action" do
        before { delete micropost_path(FactoryGirl.create(:micropost)) }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
      end
    end


    describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
      before { sign_in user }

      describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
        before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        it { should_not have_selector('title', text: 'Edit user') }
      end

      describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
        before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
      end
    end

    describe "as non-admin user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:non_admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      before { sign_in non_admin }

      describe "submitting a DELETE request to the Users#destroy action" do
        before { delete user_path(user) }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my factories.rb file

```rb
 FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}   
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"

    factory :admin do
      admin true
    end
  end

  factory :micropost do
    content "Lorem ipsum"
    user
  end
end
```

here is the spec_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
end
```

ran the FactoryGirl.create(:micropost)  from the test console and got:

```
irb(main):002:0> FactoryGirl.create(:micropost)
ArgumentError: Factory not registered: micropost
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4
.1.0/lib/factory_girl/registry.rb:24:in `find'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4
.1.0/lib/factory_girl/decorator.rb:10:in `method_missing'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4
.1.0/lib/factory_girl.rb:71:in `factory_by_name'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4
.1.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:12:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4
.1.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:19:in `block in define
_singular_strategy_method'
        from (irb):2
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9
/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9
/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.9
         from script/rails:6:in `require
 from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It's great that you posted your Github repo for everyone to clone, but please make sure that it contains the newest version of the code you're working on and, if possible, doesn't have other errors that aren't explained in your question.  At the moment, your code has bigger problems as you [forgot to add some migration code](https://github.com/princeofburma/sample_app/blob/master/db/migrate/20121228170322_add_remember_token_to_users.rb) that is causing many tests to fail.

Comment: @ Paul...Good point..forgot to push it through. It is up there now.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is in your spec_helper.rb
take a look how it manages factories definitions
https://gist.github.com/scottvrosenthal/1724370
i hope it helps.

Comment: @ Leftis....I just added the spec_helper.rb above...not sure how to relate it to the code you link to.

Comment: @user2048191 made you a pull request so factory_girl to work.

Comment: @Leftis... Here is what I get now:

Comment: I ran your code and tried to post the error code here but it is being filtered out by the "pier review" not sure how long that take or how where to post the code.  Was doing an edit to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your project and I am not getting that error. The only problem that I had seen in your application is that you don't have a `remember_token` method in your `User` model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_token
  ...
  private

    def create_remember_token
      # NoMethodError: undefined method `remember_token=' for User
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 
    end
end
```

Comment: @user2048191 Yes, but what I'm telling you is that you have wrong code in that model. Look at the comment inside `create_remember_token` that I wrote.